# US visa traveling 3 months before the expiration date B2 tourism type for a minor

Tags: usa, international-travel, b1-b2-visas

I've heard that you can't travel to the US 3 months before your visa expires. Is that true? I have just found this on some random google search, I will be traveling from the 19th february until the 14th of march. My visa expires in April 6th.

Comment: Sounds like a confusion of passport expiry and visa validity to me.

Comment: Your visa is valid for the entire duration of its validity period. If you have a one year visa, it's valid for the entire period. Some countries don't let you travel with an expiring _passport_ (within a certain period of months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may travel to the US up to and including the day on which your visa expires.  The US does not require you to have a valid visa to be in the country.  When you enter, you will receive a stamp in your passport which will indicate the date by which you must leave.  This will also be recorded in the [online I-94 database](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov).

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html

Comment: Will he ask me someone ask me for how long i want to stay?

Comment: And just for the record, whilst this answer is completely true for US visas, it is not true for most other countries.  Most countries require your visa to be  valid for the entire length of your stay.  The US is one of a few countries where it only needs to be valid on the day you enter.

Comment: @PaulGansca most likely.

Comment: @PaulGansca: Yes, but generally if you enter on B2 you will be given 6 months duration of stay no matter how long you said you wanted to stay, unless there are special circumstances like you have been staying too much in the US recently.